# Ordenar lista por dos campos

Tags: c#, lista, ordenamiento

Hola a todos nuevamente. 
Me preguntaba si se podía ordenar una lista en C# usando **Lambda** con respecto a dos valores o propiedades, es decir:

> Tengo una lista **Alumnos** y en dicha lista tengo valores como el
>   **Nombre**, **Edad** y **Genero** (Por decir algo)

Si yo quisiera ordenar por edad y nombre o por cualquiera de los anteriores campos (siempre que sean mas de uno). **¿Como podría hacerlo?**

Hasta el momento conozco solamente el `Order By` (Que toma una sobrecarga) y el `Sort` no creo que me sea util.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar alguno de los dos métodos [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx) y [ThenByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx):

Así:

```
tuLista.OrderBy(x => x.Foo).ThenBy( x => x.Bar)
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos

Comment: Va de maravilla, practico y efectivo!

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacerlo por medio de linq

```
    var agrupar = personas.GroupBy(persona => persona.Pais);
        string group = "";
        ListViewGroup g = new ListViewGroup();
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var p in agrupar)
        {
            if (p.Key.ToString() != group)
            {
                 g = new ListViewGroup(p.Key.ToString());
                 group = p.Key.ToString();
                 listView1.Groups.Add(g);
            }
//mostrás datos agrupados en listview
            foreach (var persona in p)
            {
                 ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("");
                 item.SubItems.Add(persona.Nombre);
                 item.SubItems.Add(persona.Edad.ToString());
                 item.Group = g;
                 listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Como vez usas groupby para agrupar los datos por medio de la propiedad que queras.
Aquí tengo un artículo para que comprendas mejor
[Agrupar Datos Linq](http://cristiantorresalfaro.blogspot.com/2012/08/agrupar-datos-linq-groupby-c-vbnet.html?m=1)